# Creating Node.js + socket.io Server/Client with users authentication, sending/receiving data

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sockets

I need to create web-based system with users live interaction (sending/receiving data) based on Node.js + socket.io. I've googled a lot of materials about Node.js and websockets but there are very much different solutions (using different frameworks and technologies) according different parts of my needs.

Please recommend some good and effective solution to create such web-based system where users could authenticate themselves using PHP sessions and some users directly using node.js require('mysql')..

How to keep live sessions with Node.js+socket.io after user authentication and keep updated live results even if browser window was unexpectedly closed?

How to send/receive data arrays or only changed data keys values from one user to another and send data only to specified group of users from administrator?

Please provide me some information and/or links according your experience with similar web-based system needs.

Thanks in advance for your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually build what (I think) you're describing purely using Node.JS, Socket.IO, session sockets, Redis, and passport.js

http://passportjs.org/ is an excellent library for doing user login in Node.JS

http://redis.io/topics/quickstart can be used as a session store, along with session sockets. By using a session store, you ensure that as long as the session store is active, a user's session will not be destroyed by simply closing the browser window. You would have to either kill the session store, destroy the session, or configure the session store to automatically destroy the session after some time

To send messages over a socket.io socket to a particular user, you can save his socket when he first connects. It would look something like this

```
var storedSockets = {}
io.socket.on("connection", function (socket) {
    storedSockets[socket.id] = socket
})
```

Now, whenever you want to connect to that particular socket, you can access it through storedSockets like this

```
storedSockets[socket_id_of_required_socket].emit("testing", {})
```

Of course, you need to store the socket id somewhere safe and have a reliable way to retrieve the one you want. For example, if you have a `Users` table in your database, you could store each users socket id with his record. For groups, just find all the users that fall in a group, and one after the other retrieve their sockets and send the messages